# How to deploy a WCF web service in IIS 8.0 using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, iis-8

I am stuck and can not figure out how to deploy a wcf web service in iis8.0, can any body please help me out about the detailed process of deploying a wcf web service in iis?

Are there any setting that need to be set?

What  have tried is.......

Then i created a new website in iis by giving a site name and physical path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NEWFOLDER). Then i opened the VS solution in administrative mode published it. In the dialog box opened, Created a new web application under the IIS Sites and published it. 
It was successful and could be seen in output window as well.

when click on the link of the line Connecting to http://localhost:[port#]/WebApplicationName it shows the directory structure. 
then clicked on .svc file it gives an error saying 
"The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map

Comment: What issue are you having?  What have you tried?

Comment: Just publish it. Get your publish settings right, first.

Comment: Hello John, I opened the solution in administrative mode tried publishing it. In the dialog box opened, Created a new virtual directory as well as web application under the IIS Sites and published it. Then i created a new website in iis by giving a sitename and physical path (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NEWFOLDER). But i am not able to browse it. it gives an error

Comment: What error does it give when you try and browse it?

Comment: It shows the directory structure and when i click on .svc file it http 404.3 error is thrown i.e "The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WCF Servive handlers are not installed on you server.

In Server Manager

- Expand ".Net 3.5" or ".Net 4.5", depending on Os/Framework version.
- Under "WCF Services", check the box for "HTTP-Activation" (for http binding) or "Non-http" for others bindings (tcp, named pipes, etc).
- Click "Install" Button.

That's all

Comment: Thanks Cyvermaxs, I was having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: Expand .Net 3.5 or .Net 4.5???  Where do I look for this?  We're running Server 2012.  In the Server Manager, I don't see any options anywhere for the WCF Services.